# Conversion to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help me to make below query as linq

```
SELECT E.Cosem_Object, COALESCE(A.Explanation, 'Not Available' ) As 
Explanation ,A.Unit, E.Reading , E.Unit, E.Meter_Date, E.Meter_Time from 
ENERGY_PROFILE E LEFT OUTER JOIN ALL_COSEM_OBJECTS A on 
(SUBSTRING(E.Cosem_Object,0,CHARINDEX('*',E.Cosem_Object + '*',0))) = A.Short_Cosem_Object
```

Updated:

I try

```
var query = from o in ENERGY_PROFILE 
            join e in ALL_COSEM_OBJECTS
            on o.Short_Cosem_Object equals e.Short_Cosem_Object
            select new { 
                o.Short_Cosem_Object, o.READING, e.EXPLANATION, e.UNIT 
            };
```

I need to add below line

```
SUBSTRING(E.Cosem_Object,0,CHARINDEX('*',E.Cosem_Object + '*',0)) in linq query
```

Comment: Please show your model classes.

Comment: My tip is that you a) format your query to be readable without scrolling and b) to show what you've tried. Otherwise you won't be very happy with the replies here.

Comment: Sure, I have two tables 1) ENERGY_PROFILE and 2) ALL_COSEM_OBJECTS, I want to show the Explanation and Unit from second table based on Short_Cosem_Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the exact conversion of your SQL query into LINQ, though I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are expecting since the lack of a sample and expected result:

```
 var set = from E in ENERGY_PROFILE
                     join A in ALL_COSEM_OBJECTS
                     on E.Cosem_Object.Substring(0, (E.Cosem_Object + "*").IndexOf('*')) equals A.Short_Cosem_Object
                     into joinedTb
                     from c in joinedTb.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {   
                         E.Cosem_Object,
                         Explanation = c.Explanation ?? "Not Available",
                         c.Unit,
                         E.Reading,
                         Unit2 = E.Unit,
                         E.Meter_Date,
                         E.Meter_Time
                     };
```

Comment: I make little modification,  just add more fields and it works for me. Thanks